# How to add tabs for text in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

[How can I make these be in their own tabs so users can tap and write their own things inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i7nT.png)

This is my code right now. I'm new to IOS Development and would like to know how to add the ability to tap on the names and be able to write inside of them individually.

struct LandingView: View {

```
@State private var newLandingName: String = ""
@State private var isAddingLanding = false
@State private var landings: [String] = []

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
            Circle()
                .scale(1.7)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
            Circle()
                .scale(1.3)
                .foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))
            
            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Add Your Travels")
                                        .bold()
                                    Spacer()
                                    Button(action: {
                                        isAddingLanding = true
                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                
                                List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in
                                    Text(landing).bold()
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                                        .listRowSeparatorTint(.blue)
                                }
                                .listStyle(.plain)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings!"))
                        
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {}) {
                            VStack {
                                TextField("Where did you go? \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                                    .padding()
                                Button("Add") {
                                    if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                                        landings.append(newLandingName)
                                        newLandingName = ""
                                    }
                                    isAddingLanding = false
                                }
                                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

}

I've tried adding snippets I've found online but nothing seems to work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You want users to be able to edit the text?  Add more text?  And what do you mean by 'tabs'?

Comment: yes like when they add lets say "London" (It's a travel app)..I would like for the name to be able to be tapped and you can add more info like what you did during your trip and add photos.

Comment: This feels more like a design issue than a code issue.  There's a 100 ways you could implement that, and it's not clear how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your idea, here is the code to update the values added to the list, of course this code can be enhanced to avoid boilerplate code:

```
@State private var oldLandingName: String = ""
@State private var newLandingName: String = ""
@State private var isAddingLanding = false
@State private var landings: [String] = []
@State private var isEditing = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
            Circle()
                .scale(1.7)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
            Circle()
                .scale(1.3)
                .foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Add Your Travels")
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        isAddingLanding = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in
                    Text(landing).bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                        .listRowSeparatorTint(.blue)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.isEditing = true
                            self.oldLandingName = landing
                            self.newLandingName = landing
                        }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings!"))
        
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {}) {
            VStack {
                TextField("Where did you go? \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
                Button("Add") {
                    if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                        landings.append(newLandingName)
                        newLandingName = ""
                    }
                    isAddingLanding = false
                }
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isEditing, onDismiss: {}) {
            VStack {
                TextField("", text: $newLandingName)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
                Button("Update") {
                    if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                        if let idx = landings.firstIndex(where: { $0 == $oldLandingName.wrappedValue }) {
                            self.landings[idx] = newLandingName
                        }
                    }
                    isEditing = false
                }
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I hope this help you, just try to understand the using of SwiftUI states, since we have @State and @Binding to work with structs and @StateObject and @Published to work with classes. There are another property wrappers that you could use though.